# IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2 (CNN)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am trying to do a GradCAM Heatmap in Google Colab like so:

```
from matplotlib import cm
from tf_keras_vis.gradcam import Gradcam
from tf_keras_vis.utils import normalize

gradcam = Gradcam(model, model_modifier, clone=False)

cam = gradcam(loss, S)
cam = normalize(cam)

f, ax = plt.subplots(**subprot_args)
for i in range(len(cam)):
    heatmap = np.uint8(cm.jet(cam[i])[..., :3] * 255)
    ax[i].imshow(ins[i])         <---- error
    ax[i].imshow(heatmap, cmap='jet', alpha=0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

but I get an error: `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`.

Comment: `i` is based on the length of `cam`, but you're using it to index into `ax` and `ins`, and those variables are unrelated to `cam` as far as I can see...

Comment: Any idea how I can resolve it? @JohnGordon